# Script to remove all music, pictures and videos from all profiles

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have been working on the following script, but I can't get it to work properly.

```
PSexec @list.txt -i -u UswerID -p Password PowerShell get-childitem c:\users -include *.mov,*.avi,*.asf,*.flv,*.swf,*.mpg,*.mp3,*.mp4,*.wmv,*.wav,*.jpg,*.tif,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp -recurse | {remove-item $_.fullname} > Deleted.txt 2>&1
```

I want to be able to remove all these file types from all profiles remotely on multiple Windows 7 computers.

Any help will be greatly appricated

Comment: PowerShell doesn't work when started by psexec.

Comment: Invoke-Command would probably be of interest.